# I am using expo with react native and react native web, when i run the app on an ios device it does not let me make a fetch request

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-web

here is the code i am using:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  fetch('https://d331ktkz9v8pls.cloudfront.net/api/home/banners', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    }).then((data) => {
      console.log('data', data)
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log('Error', err)
    });
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

When i run this code it gives me an error stating: Error [TypeError: Network request failed]

I tried searching for an answer but did not find one